# Matching Geopandas Dissolve with ArcGIS Dissolve on set of Polylines

Tags: python, gis, geojson, geopandas, shapely

I am trying to replicate the output from ArcGIS *Dissolve* on a set of stream flow lines using `geopandas`. Essentially the df/stream_0 layer is a stream network extracted from a DEM using [`pysheds`](https://github.com/mdbartos/pysheds). That output has some randomly overlapping reaches which I am trying to remove. Running *Dissolve* through ArcGIS Pro does this well, but I would prefer not to have to deal with ArcGIS/`ArcPy` to resolve this.

[Stream Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvE1u.jpg)

[ArcGIS Dissolve Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9Uj5.jpg)

```
#streams_0.geojson = df.shp = streams_0.shp from Dissolve Setting image
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file('streams_0.geojson')
df.head()
Out[3]: 
                                            geometry
0  LINESTRING (400017.781 3000019.250, 400017.781...
1  LINESTRING (400027.781 3000039.250, 400027.781...
2  LINESTRING (400027.781 3000039.250, 400037.781...
3  LINESTRING (400027.781 3000029.250, 400037.781...
4  LINESTRING (400047.781 3000079.250, 400047.781...
```

I have tried using gpd.dissolve() using a filler column with no luck.

```
df['dissolvefield'] = 1;
df2 = df.dissolve(by='dissolvefield')
df3 = gpd.geoseries.GeoSeries([geom for geom in df2.geometry.iloc[0].geoms])
```

Similarly tried to use unary_union in *shapely* with no luck.

```
import fiona
shape1 = fiona.open("df.shp")
first = shape1.next()

from shapely.geometry import shape
shp_geom = shape(first['geometry'])


from shapely.ops import unary_union
shape2 = unary_union(shp_geom)
```

Seems like an easy solution, wondering why I am running into so many issues. My GeoDataFrame only consists of the line geometry, so there is not necessarily another attribute I can aggregate based on. I am essentially just trying keep the geometry of the lines unchanged, but remove any overlapping features that may be there. I don't want to split the lines, and I don't want to aggregate them into multipart features.

Comment: You want a single LineString in the end? Or more LineStrings based on contiguity? You have to tell us what ArcPy does.

Comment: Apologies, I realize I may not be framing my question clearly. I am trying to take my existing df of LineStrings (roughly 4,500 lines of varying geometry), go through each of those features and find the ones that have overlapping geometries (~1,000), and then merge those matching features into one feature. The resulting ArcPy output  has around 3,500 features in it (the original 4,500, minus the 1,000 that have overlapping geometries)

Answer (score 0):

i use the unary_union, but no need to read it as shapely feature.

after reading the file and put it in GPD (you can do it straight from the *.shp file):

```
df = gpd.read_file('streams_0.geojson')
```

try to plot it to see the if the output is correct

```
df.plot()
```

than use the unary_union like this, and plot again:

```
shape2 = df.unary_union 
shape2
```

and the last step (if necessary), is to set as geopandas again:

```
# transform Geometry Collection to shapely multilinestirng
segments = [feature for feature in shape2]

# set back as geopandas
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(list(range(len(segments))),  geometry=segments, 
crs=crs)
gdf .columns = ['index', 'geometry']
```